# Base64 library that works both in C and Javascript

Tags: javascript, c, base64

Is there any base 64 encode and decode library that works for BOTH, in C and Javascript, such that it has the exact same algorithm for the encode and decode functions, so it can be used for both, desktop application client (C++) and web application client (using javascript)?

Has anyone previously written some codes for this? Well, I can also write my own if such a library is not available, but if there is an existing one, I would prefer using that to save time.

Comment: Isn't Base64 pretty standard? It's just encoding the byte values into the 64 ascii characters, right?

Comment: Base64 is a standard algorithm. All encoders and decoders should be compatible.

Comment: @Gabe: Base64 is a encoding, not an algorithm.

Comment: @KerrekSB - It's an algorithm to the extent that encodings the output of _encoders_, which are a specific class of algorithms. Namely, ones that take input in one format and "encode" it into another format as output.

Comment: @Gabe: So you mean that all implementation of base 64 library (whether it is in C, PHP, JS,Java, etc) will have the same implementation for the encode and decode functions? I guess each of these library developers may write their own encode and decode functions, which are different from one another.

Comment: @all_by_grace: So what if the functions are different - they produce the same *results*!

Comment: @all_by_grace: Yes, all Base64 decoders will be able to read the output of all Base64 encoders.

Comment: All standard compatible implantation will create the same result.  that's why you have standards and interfaces so you don't have to worry about the details.

Comment: Ahh okay thanks for clarifying that, at first I thought that they will produce different results, hence will make it un-portable with other base64 library implementation.

Comment: There're different standard alphabets (look for base64 at wiki), but default one is the same for all implementations: `+/`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any Base64 encoding routines for C, JavaScript, or anything else should be interoperable. If they're not, they're not Base64. That [may not have always been true in the past](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#Variants_summary_table), but as long as both implementations use [the same encoding table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#Examples) they should work together.